# Quick-and-dirty class constructor for MATLAB?

Tags: oop, class, matlab, constructor

I am trying to make MATLAB a bit more usable than it is (for me), and one of the things which I always wanted to fix is a better class constructor. I want to have the following interface:

```
MyClass.new(some_args).method1;

# instead of classical:
obj = MyClass(some_args);
obj.method1;
```

I can easily achieve this by defining a static method `new`:

```
classdef MyClass
  methods
    function obj = MyClass(varargin); end
    function method1(obj,varargin); end
  end

  methods (Static)
    function obj = new(varargin); obj = MyClass(varargin{:}); end
  end
end
```

But this requires adding such method to all classes, and therefore it is not very elegant/convenient. I thought that I could go around it by defining a common class with the following constructor

```
classdef CommonClass
  methods (Static)
    function obj = new(varargin)
      # getting name of the current file (Object), i.e. basename(__FILE__)
      try clear E; E; catch E, [s, s] = fileparts(E.stack(1).file); end;
      # creating object with name $s
      obj = eval([s '(varargin{:})']);
    end
  end
end

classdef MyClass < CommonClass
end
```

However, this doesn't work because MATLAB calls `new()` from `Object.m`, and therefore I get instance of `Object` instead of `MyClass`.

Any ideas how I can improve it?

---

EDIT1:

I would like it to work also for classes created inside other ones:

```
classdef MyAnotherClass < CommonClass
  methods
    function obj = MyAnotherClass
      child = MyClass.new;
    end
  end
end

>> MyAnotherClass.new
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I don't see the problem with calling the constructor as is, but if you do want to have it called via `new`, the `getStaticCallingClassName` below might be of use to you.

Here's how you'd use it:

```
classdef CommonClass
  methods (Static)
    function obj = new(varargin)
      %# find out which class we have to create
      className = getStaticCallingClassName;
      constructor = str2func(sprintf('@%s'className));
      %# creating object with name $s
      obj = constructor(varargin{:});
    end
  end
end

classdef MyClass < CommonClass
end
```

With this, you can call

```
obj = MyClass.new(input,arguments);
```

And here's `getStaticCallingClassName`:

```
function className = getStaticCallingClassName
%GETSTATICCALLINGCLASSNAME finds the classname used when invoking an (inherited) static method.
%
% SYNOPSIS: className = getStaticCallingClassName
%
% INPUT none
%
% OUTPUT className: name of class that was used to invoke an (inherited) static method
%
% EXAMPLE
%
%   Assume you define a static method in a superclass
%       classdef super < handle
%       methods (Static)
%           doSomething
%               % do something here
%           end
%       end
%       end
%
%   Also, you define two subclasses
%       classdef sub1 < super
%       end
%
%       classdef sub2 < super
%       end
%
%   Both subclasses inherit the static method. However, you may be
%   interested in knowing which subclass was used when calling the static
%   method. If you call the subclass programmatically, you can easily pass
%   the name of the subclass as an input argument, but you may want to be
%   able to call the method from command line without any input and still
%   know the class name.
%   getStaticCallingClassName solves this problem. Calling it in the above
%   static method 'doSomething', it returns 'sub1' if the static method was
%   invoked as sub1.doSomething. It also works if you create an instance of
%   the subclass first, and then invoke the static method from the object
%   (e.g. sc = sub1; sc.doSomething returns 'sub1' if .doSomething calls
%   getStaticCallingClassName)
%   
%   NOTE: getStaticCallingClassName reads the last workspace command from
%         history. This is an undocumented feature. Thus,
%         getStaticCallingClassName may not work in future releases.
%   
% created with MATLAB ver.: 7.9.0.3470 (R2009b) on Mac OS X  Version: 10.5.7 Build: 9J61 
%
% created by: Jonas Dorn
% DATE: 16-Jun-2009
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% get the last entry of the command line from the command history
javaHistory=com.mathworks.mlservices.MLCommandHistoryServices.getSessionHistory;
lastCommand = javaHistory(end).toCharArray';%'# SO formatting
% find string before the last dot.
tmp = regexp(lastCommand,'(?:=|\.)?(\w+)\.\w+\(?(?:.*)[;,]*\s*$','tokens');
try
    className = tmp{1}{1};
catch me
    className = [];
end
% if you assign an object, and then call the static method from the
% instance, the above regexp returns the variable name. We can get the
% className through getting the class of xx.empty.
if ~isempty(className)
    className = evalin('base',sprintf('class(%s.empty);',className));
end
```

Comment: Your method is interesting, but it doesn't take into account that classes may be created via `new` inside other classes :) It's not the MATLAB style, I know. I just wanted to get at least some taste of Ruby in my m-scripts.

Comment: @Andrei Fokau: If you call `CommonClass.new`, then you have to pass `'MyClass'` as an argument to let MATLAB know that you want to create an object of class `MyClass`. However, if you run `MyClass.new`, which calles the static method `new` of the superclass, then `getStaticCallingClassName` is exactly what you need. See my edit.

Comment: If I try to execute `MyAnotherClass.new` which calls `MyClass.new` in its constructor (see my updated question), then I get an infinite loop. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @Andrei Fokau: Ideally, the `new` method also accepts the class name as optional input. Thus, if you call `new` from within code, you can hard-code which class should be constructed.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something, but what's wrong with

```
method1(MyClass(some_args))
```

? (I use this pattern all the time).